# Disable Indexes option in apache2 for specific hosts

Tags: apache, .htaccess, security, webserver

Is there a way to disable indexes within a directory for a single host in apache2 site configuration while allowing all other hosts to list the directory?  I know how to allow Indexes and disable host access to a directory, but I want the host in question the ability to execute items within the directory, just not list them in a web browser.

This is an example of what I do not want:

```
<Directory /path/to/dir>
    Options Indexes
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
    deny from 10.0.0.10/32
</Directory>
```

The block above allows indexes in /path/to/dir for everyone except for anyone connecting from 10.0.0.10.  So 10.0.0.10 is successfully denied access but that access includes any type of access, not just viewing the directory structure in a web browser.

This is another example of what I do not want:

```
<Directory /path/to/dir>
    Options -Indexes
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

The block directly above disables indexes for everyone no matter what host they are connecting from.

TLDR; How do I disable indexes for a single host while allowing indexes for all other hosts?

Comment: You can put an ..htaccess file inside that directory with `Options -Indexes` at the top.

Comment: I may not have explained the scenario perfectly.  I only want the Options -Indexes to apply to a specific host or IP address, not for everyone connecting to the directory in a browser.  Is there a way to specify the Options -Indexes for a single host or IP address?